# Get program to loop infinitely and not exit on System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException

Tags: c#, multithreading

How would I get my program to loop the methods below infinitely and not exit with the following message after 20-30 seconds: `A first chance exception of type 'System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException' occurred in mscorlib.dll`.

```
    private static void Main()
    {
        using (var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)))
        {
            Task task = GenerateBids(cancellationTokenSource.Token);
            task.Wait(cancellationTokenSource.Token);
        }
    }

    private static async Task GenerateBids(CancellationToken cancel)
    {
        while (!cancel.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            try
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++)
                    MethodA();
                await Task.Delay(2000, cancel);
                if (cancel.IsCancellationRequested)
                    return;
                MethodB();
                MethodC();
                MethodD();
                await Task.Delay(2000, cancel);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
task.Wait(cancellationTokenSource.Token);
```

write

```
task.Wait();
```

otherwise the call to `Wait` is cancelled with this exception after 30 seconds...

Comment: Will it loop through the methods continuously or just pause at this stage?

Comment: `task.Wait();` will block until the task from `GenerateBids` has completed